# what's the magic behind ndb.Model constructor?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

dear all

It was a surpass for me to know I can initial properties of my ndb model as shown below. I just need to use keyword arguments when creating a new instance of my entity class.

```
class MyModel(ndb.Model):
  foo = ndb.StringProperty()
  bar = ndb.StringProperty()
  baz = ndb.StringProperty()

model_instance = MyModel(foo='foo', bar='bar', baz='baz')
```

This confused me, cause I haven't created any constructor in my class. How can Python know how to set property without constructor?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the doc. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Constructor
The Model class has constructor and you can passed in keyword arguments to map to properties. Since you do not define constructor for your class, it's using the Model constructor

Comment: And there is other behavior under the hood as metaclasses are used. I would also go as far as to say do not override __init__ method unless you REALLY know what you are doing.